# How to make a flutter app that contains a background image stretched over the entire screen, circle button with an image inside that returns sentence?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-layout

Using flutter, dart and vscode to make an android app.

I need to create a flutter app with an image that stretches over the entire background.
[Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKQi6.jpg) And on top of this I need a circle button with and image inside, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymsn7.png), that when pressed will return a sentence above it. I know how to make the background part, but every example of a circular button with an image inside hasn't worked.

This is the code I have so far for the background image, you don't have to use this to help me I'm open to anything.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                  heightFactor: 1.2,
                  widthFactor: 1.1,
                  child: DecoratedBox(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/images/gext.png"),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ); 
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyPage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  bool _shouldDisplaySentence = false;

  Widget _buildTopButton() {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => this.setState(() {
        _shouldDisplaySentence = !_shouldDisplaySentence;
      }),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 60.0,
        width: 60.0,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60.0 / 2),
          child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/100'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(
              'https://picsum.photos/1000',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Column(children: [
                if (_shouldDisplaySentence) Text('The secret sentence is showing'),
                _buildTopButton(),
              ]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

First I simplified the way you display the background image.
Then I use a gesture detector instead of using any kind of button. I round the image by passing it into a `ClipRRect` and give it the proper radius.

If you want some effects when the button is tapped, then we might not want to choose a Gesture Detector.

Note the images are random and will change every time you reload.

Comment: I'm getting an error. No MediaQuery widget ancestor found.

Comment: @mjnitro my bad, I just updated the snippet to separate the page from the app so you have access to the media query. Should work now